# Display jpegs coming from http post

Tags: http, post, jpeg, mjpeg

I'm sending jpegs to a web server via Http POST. I can access the bytes of each jpeg file that reaches the web server.

Now I want do display these jpeg as they reach the web server, as a mjpeg video.

How can I do it?

Please help!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg.

See http://electron.mit.edu/~gsteele/ffmpeg/

C.